# S3 private bucket with Cloudfront access via Signed Url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I have the following setup working:

- Private S3 buckets with Cloudfront Distribution
- User logs into portal and has access to files from S3 which are served through Cloudfront Signed Urls valid for a certain period of time.

Currently, it is possible that a user copies that Url via for example Google Debugger and share with others. I wonder if it is possible to further saveguard the files so they can only be opened via the portal domain. I was looking into bucket policies similar to

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": [
                    "http://www.example.com/*",
                    "http://example.com/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

While it works sometimes, it does not all the time. If I request 5 files it would work for 1 and not for 4. I wonder if this has something to do with Cloudfront on top of S3?

Has anyone of you a suggestion how to go about?

Thanks,
Moz

Comment: Just don't use pre-signed url if you are worried about sharing. Make the request go through the backend of your portal and verify if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Using `aws:Referer` is generally a bad idea. It can be easily faked.

See: [Referer spoofing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing)

If you are worried about a pre-signed URL being shared, then reduce the expiry period on the pre-signed URL.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should go for [Signed Cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) instead of [Signed Urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html).